# jQuery - using length to find div after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

UPDATE:

The issue was the div was in a div that was hidden, when divs are hidden length, offset(), position() don't work properly.

## // Original Post below.

This should be simple.

I'm trying to test if a div exsists on the page after an ajax .html() output

```
if($('#'+mydiv).length != 1) {
   // do stuff
}
```

there is only one problem, if the div your searching for is not there when (document).ready fires then  .length doesn't see it.

Comment: Can you show the code of the ajax call, One common mistake is to not wait for the ajax call to finish, remember that it is asynchronous and the initial call will return to the script before any response from the server. Any code that is to interact with any new content need to be in a callback method to the ajax call.

Comment: is the div you're checking from the ajax response?

Comment: You seem to be testing correctly if the div exists,what exactly is the problem then?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the  **size()** method

```
if($('#'+mydiv).size() != 1) {
   // do stuff
}
```

This recounts the number of matching elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

If you are performing an async request, which I assume you are (`async:true` in JQuery) then you should be using size() in the success callback of your function, after the content has been added.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success: function(response) {
                $('#container').html(response.data);
                if($('someSearch').size() > 0)
                    alert('exists');
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
$('#loader').load('url', {variable1:var1}, function () { 
    if($('#'+mydiv).length != 1) {
       // do stuff
    }
});
```

That should look for anything loaded after your load call is finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the exact same problem with the ticker after page content has been loaded using ajax - my solution was to use the **livequery** plugin : http://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery/downloads. I then use it in the following way:

```
$('.ticker').livequery(function() {     
    if ($(this).length > 0) {
        var thisObj = $(this);
        if (thisObj.length > 1) {
            jQuery.each(thisObj, function() {                   
                systemObject.tickerExe($(this));
            });
        } else {    
            systemObject.tickerExe(thisObj);
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your div isn't hidden when checking length. Usually, hidden div's can cause lots of problems.